# Problema ao fazer o update de senha no DB. - PHP,PDO, MYSQL-

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

Estou chamando uma função de uma classe.Essa função é usada para alterar a senha do usuário no db.

O arquivo da classe contem:

```
    <?php
class Usuario
{

    private $pdo;  /*criando variavel para usar nas funçoes*/
    public $msgErro = "";

    public function conectar($nome, $host, $usuario, $senha)
    {
        global $pdo;
        global $msgErro;
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . $nome . ";host=" . $host, $usuario, $senha);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $msgErro - $e->getMessage(); /*pega a mensagem de erro do php e joga na variavel msegErro e mostra pro usuario.*/
        }
    }
    public function cadastrar($nome, $email, $senha)
    {
        global $pdo;
        //global $msgErro;
        //verificando se existe usuario cadastrado.
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE email=:e"); //pega o id do usuario buscando pelo emial preenchido no cadastro
        $sql->bindValue(":e", $email);  //substitui o :e pelo email preenchido no cadastro
        $sql->execute();
        if ($sql->rowCount() > 0) //verificando houve resposta na consulta
            {
                return false; // ja tem cadastro
            } else {
            //caso nao tenha
            $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, email, senha) VALUES (:n,:e,:s)");
            $sql->bindValue(":n", $nome);
            $sql->bindValue(":e", $email);
            $sql->bindValue(":s", md5($senha));
            $sql->execute();
            return true;
        }
    }
    public function logar($email, $senha)
    {
        global $pdo;
        //global $msgErro;
        /*verificar se o email e senha estao cadastrados, se sim*/
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE email= :e AND senha =:s");
        $sql->bindValue(":e", $email);
        $sql->bindValue(":s", md5($senha));
        $sql->execute();
        if ($sql->rowCount() > 0) //verificando houve resposta na consulta
            {
                //entrar no sistema criando uma (sessao)
                $dado = $sql->fetch(); //transforma o retorno da query em array com os nomes das colunas
                session_start();       //iniciando a sessao

                if ($_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $dado['id_usuario']) {

                    return true;
                }
            }
    }




    public function trocarSenha($novasenhaup, $id_usuario)
    {

        global $pdo;

        $sql = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET senha=:novasenhaup WHERE id_usuario=:id_usuario");
        $sql->bindValue(":novasenhaup", $novasenhaup);
        $sql->bindValue(":id_usuario", $id_usuario);
        $sql->execute();
        return $sql;





    }
}


?>
```

A função em especifico é a trocarSenha:

```
    public function trocarSenha($novasenhaup, $id_usuario)
    {

        global $pdo;

        $sql = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET senha=:novasenhaup WHERE id_usuario=:id_usuario");
        $sql->bindValue(":novasenhaup", $novasenhaup);
        $sql->bindValue(":id_usuario", $id_usuario);
        $sql->execute();
        return $sql;

    }
```

No arquivo alterarsenha.php tenho o seguinte na parte do php.

Mas não consigo fazer o update da senha.Tenho o erro:
Notice: Undefined variable: id_usuario in C:\laragon\www

```
<body>
<div id="corpo-form-cad">
    <h1></h1>
    <form method="POST">

        <input type="password" name="novasenha" placeholder="Senha" maxlength="20">
        <input type="password" name="confSenha" placeholder="Confirmar senha">
        <input type="submit" value="Trocar senha" class="entrar">

    </form>
</div>
```

No mesmo arquivo parte em php:

```
if (isset($_POST['novasenha'])) {

$novasenhaup = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['novasenha']));
$confirmarSenha = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['confSenha']));

if (!empty($novasenhaup) && !empty($confirmarSenha)) {

    $u->conectar("sistem_login", "localhost", "root", "");
    if ($u->msgErro == "") {


        if ($novasenhaup == $confirmarSenha) {
            if ($update = $u->trocarSenha($novasenhaup, $id_usuario)) {
                echo '<br>';
                echo "Cadastro realizado com sucesso!";
            }
        } else {
            echo '<br>';
            echo "Senhas não conferem!";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Erro: " . $u->msgErro;
    }
} else {
    echo "Preencha todos os campos!";
}
```

Não consigo fazer o update da senha de forma alguma, acredito deva ser apenas um detalhe em alguma linha.
Lembrando que na parte do php eu chamo a classe da seguinte forma:

require_once 'classes/usuarios.php';

$u = new Usuario;

Atenciosamente
Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei conseguindo resolver com apenas duas linhas.
Como o erro era que a variável id_usuario estava indefinida,fiz da seguinte forma.
No arquivo que faz o recadastro:

```
session_start();
$id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
```